# apache mod_proxy error os10060 and returning 503?

Tags: apache, proxy

Can't get to my site. Apache gives the following error message:

> [Fri Sep 05 08:47:42 2008] [error] (OS 10060)A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.  : proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 10.10.10.1:80 (10.10.10.1) failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you connect to the proxied host (10.10.10.1) directly?  Is it functioning normally?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html

> Your Web server is effectively 'closed for repair'. It is still functioning minimally because it can at least respond with a 503 status code, but full service is impossible i.e. your Web site is simply unavailable. There are a myriad possible reasons for this, but generally it is because of some human intervention by the operators of your Web server machine. You can usually expect that someone is working on the problem, and normal service will resume as soon as possible.

You need to restart the webserver then figure out why it shut it self down.